# Getting Black screen after installing 12.04 on new Mac Pro

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, macosx

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my new Mac Pro. I had some problems because bootcamp did not allow me to partition the hd without a Windows cd.

I inserted a Windows cd and did the partition and then I stopped the installation. I completed the installation of Ubuntu that now works.

The problem is that **Grub can't start** Mac OS. It sees the Mac OS X in the menu but if I try to start it I have a black screen or sometime just the boot manager.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem.
[here's a link that might clarify things for you.][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it